# $p$ prime and $m_p$ a proper divisor of $p−1$. Is it $\sigma(m_p)<p$ for every $p$ and $m_p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Along the problem I'm facing, I've come to the following lemma (if it is true):

Let $p$ be a prime and $m_p$ a *proper* divisor of $p-1$. Then the sum of all the divisors of $m_p$, say $\sigma(m_p)$, is less than $p$.

For example, take $p=13$; then, for $m_{13}=6$: $1+2+3+6=12<13$, and likewise for $m_{13}=4,3,2,1$. Or take $p=31$; then for $m_{31}=15$ we have: $1+3+5+15=24<31$, or for $m_{31}=10$: $1+2+5+10=18<31$, and likewise for $m_{31}=5,3,1$.

Is it true for every $p$ and $m_p$?

Comment: It might be true for sum of its proper divisors, but for this version of the question, the counter-example is given below. (I'm trying this case but I don't know what it will give.)

Comment: I do think that I have some interesting pieces of information. For example, if there exist infinitely many primes of the form $n!+1$, then this ($\sigma(m_p)-m_p < p$) is not true. The proof is a bit lengthy, and I might have an error or two.

Comment: From the list given here, https://primes.utm.edu/top20/page.php?id=30 letting $p = 150209!+1$, and $m_p = 150209!/2$ gives us a counter-example. Because of the fact that:

$$\frac{\sigma(m_p)}{m_p} = \sum_{d|m_p}\frac{1}{d}\geq \sum_{d\leq m_p}\frac{1}{d}-\frac{1}{2^k} \geq 11.9 > \frac{p}{m_p}+1$$ where $k$ is the smallest number such that $2^{k+1}> p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $p=37$, $m_{37}=18$. Then $1+2+3+6+9+18 = 39 > 37.$

Comment: gosh, I should have done one step further than $31$... I'll accept your answer as soon as I'm allowed.

Comment: Somewhat a coincidence. I just looked at $2n+1$ for $n$ an abundant number: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundant_number