# $p$ prime and $m_p$ a proper divisor of $p−1$. Is it $\sigma(m_p)-\nu(m_p)<p-2$ for every $p$ and $m_p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

(This is a sharper version of [this other](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4328490/943729) question of mine.)

Along the problem I'm facing, I've come to the following lemma (if it is true):

Let $p$ be a prime and $m_p$ a *proper* divisor of $p-1$. Then the difference between the sum of all the divisors of $m_p$, say $\sigma(m_p)$, and their number, say $\nu(m_p)$, is less than $p-2$.

Examples:

- $p=13$; then, for $m_{13}=6$: $1+2+3+6-4=8<11$, and likewise for $m_{13}=4,3,2,1$;
- $p=31$; then for $m_{31}=15$ we have: $1+3+5+15-4=20<29$, or for $m_{31}=10$: $1+2+5+10-4=14<29$, and likewise for $m_{31}=5,3,2,1$;
- $p=37$; then for $m_{37}=18$ we have: $1+2+3+6+9+18-6=33<35$, and likewise for $m_{37}=9,6,3,2,1$;
- $p=101$; then for $m_{101}=50$ we have: $1+2+5+10+25+50-6=87<99$, and likewise for $m_{101}=25,20,10,5,2,1$.

Is it true for every $p$ and $m_p$?

Comment: Nothing systematic about it, just asking the computer for some random primes. E.g. $p = 1747729$, $m_p = 873864$ is a counterexample. Almost certainly not the smallest.

Comment: The smallest counterexample appears to be $p = 61$, $m_p = 30$.

Comment: @prets the systematic way is to increas $m= 2,3,4,5,6,...$ for each find the smallest prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod m$  and do the test.  If it works for minimal $p$  it also works for larger $p$

Comment: @WillJagy Perfectly true! For that original comment I was on my way to a meeting and just punched a random prime into PARI/GP for fun and happened to stumble upon a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By computer search, $p = 61$ and $m_p = 30$ seems to be the smallest counterexample. We get $\sigma(m_p) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 5 + 6 + 10 + 15 + 30 = 72$ and $\nu(m_p) = 8$, so $\sigma(m_p) - \nu(m_p) = 72 - 8 = 64$.

Answer (score 1):

here are the counterexamples from $m=30$ to $m = 210,$ those being consecutive primorials. The primorial thing seems to die out after

```
m: 2310   p:   4621    sig:   6912 nu: 32  diff:  6880  WOW 2310 =  2 3 5 7 11
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

```
m:   30   p:     61    sig:     72 nu: 8  diff:  64  WOW 30 =  2 3 5
m:   36   p:     73    sig:     91 nu: 9  diff:  82  WOW 36 =  2^2 3^2
m:   48   p:     97    sig:    124 nu: 10  diff:  114  WOW 48 =  2^4 3
m:   54   p:    109    sig:    120 nu: 8  diff:  112  WOW 54 =  2 3^3
m:   56   p:    113    sig:    120 nu: 8  diff:  112  WOW 56 =  2^3 7
m:   78   p:    157    sig:    168 nu: 8  diff:  160  WOW 78 =  2 3 13
m:   90   p:    181    sig:    234 nu: 12  diff:  222  WOW 90 =  2 3^2 5
m:   96   p:    193    sig:    252 nu: 12  diff:  240  WOW 96 =  2^5 3
m:  114   p:    229    sig:    240 nu: 8  diff:  232  WOW 114 =  2 3 19
m:  120   p:    241    sig:    360 nu: 16  diff:  344  WOW 120 =  2^3 3 5
m:  138   p:    277    sig:    288 nu: 8  diff:  280  WOW 138 =  2 3 23
m:  140   p:    281    sig:    336 nu: 12  diff:  324  WOW 140 =  2^2 5 7
m:  156   p:    313    sig:    392 nu: 12  diff:  380  WOW 156 =  2^2 3 13
m:  168   p:    337    sig:    480 nu: 16  diff:  464  WOW 168 =  2^3 3 7
m:  174   p:    349    sig:    360 nu: 8  diff:  352  WOW 174 =  2 3 29
m:  176   p:    353    sig:    372 nu: 10  diff:  362  WOW 176 =  2^4 11
m:  186   p:    373    sig:    384 nu: 8  diff:  376  WOW 186 =  2 3 31
m:  198   p:    397    sig:    468 nu: 12  diff:  456  WOW 198 =  2 3^2 11
m:  200   p:    401    sig:    465 nu: 12  diff:  453  WOW 200 =  2^3 5^2
m:  204   p:    409    sig:    504 nu: 12  diff:  492  WOW 204 =  2^2 3 17
m:  210   p:    421    sig:    576 nu: 16  diff:  560  WOW 210 =  2 3 5 7
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Alright, noticed that the above counterexamples all have the minimal prime $p = 1 + 2m.$   It is also possible to have counterexamples with $p=1+3m,$  listed below, but $p \geq 1+4m$  seems to allow no counterexamples at all.

```
m:  540   p:   1621    sig:   1680 nu: 24  diff:  1656  WOW 540 =  2^2 3^3 5  THREE   
m:  720   p:   2161    sig:   2418 nu: 30  diff:  2388  WOW 720 =  2^4 3^2 5  THREE   
m:  840   p:   2521    sig:   2880 nu: 32  diff:  2848  WOW 840 =  2^3 3 5 7  THREE   
m: 1620   p:   4861    sig:   5082 nu: 30  diff:  5052  WOW 1620 =  2^2 3^4 5  THREE   
m: 2040   p:   6121    sig:   6480 nu: 32  diff:  6448  WOW 2040 =  2^3 3 5 17  THREE   
m: 2160   p:   6481    sig:   7440 nu: 40  diff:  7400  WOW 2160 =  2^4 3^3 5  THREE   
m: 2184   p:   6553    sig:   6720 nu: 32  diff:  6688  WOW 2184 =  2^3 3 7 13  THREE   
m: 2376   p:   7129    sig:   7200 nu: 32  diff:  7168  WOW 2376 =  2^3 3^3 11  THREE   
m: 2520   p:   7561    sig:   9360 nu: 48  diff:  9312  WOW 2520 =  2^3 3^2 5 7  THREE   
m: 2700   p:   8101    sig:   8680 nu: 36  diff:  8644  WOW 2700 =  2^2 3^3 5^2  THREE   
m: 2772   p:   8317    sig:   8736 nu: 36  diff:  8700  WOW 2772 =  2^2 3^2 7 11  THREE   
m: 2880   p:   8641    sig:   9906 nu: 42  diff:  9864  WOW 2880 =  2^6 3^2 5  THREE   
m: 3000   p:   9001    sig:   9360 nu: 32  diff:  9328  WOW 3000 =  2^3 3 5^3  THREE   
m: 3300   p:   9901    sig:  10416 nu: 36  diff:  10380  WOW 3300 =  2^2 3 5^2 11  THREE   
m: 3720   p:  11161    sig:  11520 nu: 32  diff:  11488  WOW 3720 =  2^3 3 5 31  THREE   
m: 3900   p:  11701    sig:  12152 nu: 36  diff:  12116  WOW 3900 =  2^2 3 5^2 13  THREE   
m: 4032   p:  12097    sig:  13208 nu: 42  diff:  13166  WOW 4032 =  2^6 3^2 7  THREE   
m: 4140   p:  12421    sig:  13104 nu: 36  diff:  13068  WOW 4140 =  2^2 3^2 5 23  THREE   
m: 4200   p:  12601    sig:  14880 nu: 48  diff:  14832  WOW 4200 =  2^3 3 5^2 7  THREE   
m: 4284   p:  12853    sig:  13104 nu: 36  diff:  13068  WOW 4284 =  2^2 3^2 7 17  THREE   
m: 4560   p:  13681    sig:  14880 nu: 40  diff:  14840  WOW 4560 =  2^4 3 5 19  THREE   
m: 5040   p:  15121    sig:  19344 nu: 60  diff:  19284  WOW 5040 =  2^4 3^2 5 7  THREE   
m: 5220   p:  15661    sig:  16380 nu: 36  diff:  16344  WOW 5220 =  2^2 3^2 5 29  THREE   
m: 5292   p:  15877    sig:  15960 nu: 36  diff:  15924  WOW 5292 =  2^2 3^3 7^2  THREE   
m: 5460   p:  16381    sig:  18816 nu: 48  diff:  18768  WOW 5460 =  2^2 3 5 7 13  THREE
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Correction, ratio 4 is possible, just need to keep looking at larger and larger $m$

```
m:60480   p: 241921    sig: 243840 nu: 112  diff:  243728  WOW 60480 =  2^6 3^3 5 7  FOUR OR MORE   
m:83160   p: 332641    sig: 345600 nu: 128  diff:  345472  WOW 83160 =  2^3 3^3 5 7 11  FOUR OR MORE   
m:128520   p: 514081    sig: 518400 nu: 128  diff:  518272  WOW 128520 =  2^3 3^3 5 7 17  FOUR OR MORE   
m:184800   p: 739201    sig: 749952 nu: 144  diff:  749808  WOW 184800 =  2^5 3 5^2 7 11  FOUR OR MORE   
m:211680   p: 846721    sig: 861840 nu: 144  diff:  861696  WOW 211680 =  2^5 3^3 5 7^2  FOUR OR MORE   
m:231840   p: 927361    sig: 943488 nu: 144  diff:  943344  WOW 231840 =  2^5 3^2 5 7 23  FOUR OR MORE   
m:240240   p: 960961    sig: 999936 nu: 160  diff:  999776  WOW 240240 =  2^4 3 5 7 11 13  FOUR OR MORE   
m:272160   p:1088641    sig: 1100736 nu: 144  diff:  1100592  WOW 272160 =  2^5 3^5 5 7  FOUR OR MORE   
m:277200   p:1108801    sig: 1199328 nu: 180  diff:  1199148  WOW 277200 =  2^4 3^2 5^2 7 11  FOUR OR MORE   
m:289800   p:1159201    sig: 1160640 nu: 144  diff:  1160496  WOW 289800 =  2^3 3^2 5^2 7 23  FOUR OR MORE   
m:292320   p:1169281    sig: 1179360 nu: 144  diff:  1179216  WOW 292320 =  2^5 3^2 5 7 29  FOUR OR MORE   
m:299880   p:1199521    sig: 1200420 nu: 144  diff:  1200276  WOW 299880 =  2^3 3^2 5 7^2 17  FOUR OR MORE   
m:347760   p:1391041    sig: 1428480 nu: 160  diff:  1428320  WOW 347760 =  2^4 3^3 5 7 23  FOUR OR MORE   
m:383040   p:1532161    sig: 1584960 nu: 168  diff:  1584792  WOW 383040 =  2^6 3^2 5 7 19  FOUR OR MORE   
m:411840   p:1647361    sig: 1664208 nu: 168  diff:  1664040  WOW 411840 =  2^6 3^2 5 11 13  FOUR OR MORE   
m:428400   p:1713601    sig: 1798992 nu: 180  diff:  1798812  WOW 428400 =  2^4 3^2 5^2 7 17  FOUR OR MORE   
m:436800   p:1747201    sig: 1763776 nu: 168  diff:  1763608  WOW 436800 =  2^6 3 5^2 7 13  FOUR OR MORE
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Comment: getting there: these counterexamples all have $p = 1+2m.$